# Copy single file instead of entire directory in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

Let's suppose that I am in some directory with two subdirectories, `a` and `b`. `a` has two files in it: `t1.txt` and `t2.txt`. That is, I have the following directory structure:

```
/.
  /a
    t1.txt
    t2.txt
  /b
```

I want to copy the file `t1.txt` from the `a` directory into the `b` directory.

I tried the following command

```
copy /b a/t1.txt b/t1.txt
```

but it copies the *entire* `a` directory into the `b` directory.

Why does this happen, and how can I make it so that only the `t1.txt` file is copied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When copying to a new directory, you only need to [specify the new directory](http://www.computerhope.com/copyhlp.htm). So

```
 copy /b a\t1.txt b
```

should work.

That said, I don't think additionally specifying the file name would cause the error you've described -- the official help text says "Destination can consist of a drive letter and colon, a folder name, a file name, or a combination of these," which to me implies that how you have it is fine.

I've also reversed the slashes -- were you using forward slashes in your batch file or is that a typo in the post? Maybe that was the problem?